# Error while trying to call method "cannot be applied to given types"

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a call by value method to solve the hypotenuse, while letting the user input the sides. 
I am getting this error "java:42: error: method hypotenuse in class Hypotenuse cannot be applied to given types;"

```
class Hypotenuse
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   //Start bracket for main program
        double katetEn = 1.0;
        double katetTo = 1.0;
        double hyp;
        int svar;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Dette programmet løser hypotenusen til en rettvinklet trekant"); //Let the user know the program purpose

        do
        {   //Start bracket of do loop
            System.out.println("Skriv in første katet i trekanten");    //Tell user to input the length of the first side
            katetEn = input.nextDouble();   //Set variable to users input value
                if (katetEn >= 0)   //Check that the value isn't negative
                {
                    System.out.println("Verdien du skrev inn er: " + katetEn + " Skriv inn verdien til det andre katetet:");    //Display the first side value
                }
                else    //If the value is negative, end the program with this "else"
                {
                    System.out.println("Du har skrevet inn en negativ verdi!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            katetTo = input.nextDouble();   //Set variable to users input value
                if (katetTo >= 0)   //Check that the value again isn't negative
                {
                    System.out.println("Verdiene du skrev inn er " + katetEn + " og " + katetTo );  //Display both values entered by the user
                }
                else    //End the program if value is negative
                {
                    System.out.println("Du har skrevet inn en negativ verdi!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                    System.out.println("Hypotenusen har verdien: " + hypotenuse(hyp) ); //Display the hypotenuse, given the two sides with user input values

            System.out.println("Vil du finne hypotenusen til en annen rettvinklet trekant?");   //Ask the user to continue loop or end
            System.out.println("JA = 1 / Nei = 0");                                             //Let the user know to input 1 for yes i want to continue, or 0 for no i don't
            System.out.println("Skriv inn et heltall for å svare på spørsmålet");               //Ask user for an int value to provide an answer
                svar = input.nextInt();
        }   //End bracket for do loop
        while (svar != 0);      //While statement to either continue loop, or end the program as requested.
    }                           //End bracket for main
    //Method for solving hypotenuse
    static double hypotenuse(double katetEn, double katetTo)
    {                           //Start bracket for hypotenuse method
        double hyp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(katetEn, 2) + Math.pow(katetTo, 2));
    return hyp;
    }                           //End bracket for hypotenuse method
}
```

I expect to see the result of the method displayed in my hypotenuse(hyp) );
but i get the error "Hypotenuse.java:42: error: method hypotenuse in class Hypotenuse cannot be applied to given types;" instead

Comment: You're trying to pass a *single* value (`hyp`) to the `hypotensue` method, but it has two parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
hypotenuse(hyp);
```

That is how you **use* that method.

That here:

```
static double hypotenuse(double katetEn, double katetTo)
```

is how you **declared** it.

Note: you declared it to be called with **two** parameters. Not one!

In other words: the message tells you at which line you are trying to invoke a method ... in a way that the compiler can't comprehend. What you do then: look at that line. And compare the usage with the declaration.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, I just didn't understand that i then had to type in hypotenuse(katetEn, katetTo) instead of hypotenuse(hyp).

Comment: @Matrucious You are very welcome, I appreciate the quick accept!